# Missfont error while batch processing using python script

Tags: pdftex, missing

I have `Ubuntu 16.04` system with `TeX Live 2015` installed. When I compile my `.tex` file using terminal it works fine. But I want to work with large number of files so I have written python script which runs the same command. When `.tex` files get compiled from this script, the compiler cannot find various fonts, and `missfont.log` file is generated in the directory. Can someone please help me?

`I am using python's subprocess.call() method (if it helps)`

Comment: The fact that you're calling it from a script should not (cannot) make a difference. (If your Python script calls a TeX program with certain command-line arguments, then the effect should be exactly that of calling the TeX program directly with those arguments.) The more likely issue is that one or some of the large number of files is different from the others (in that it refers to missing fonts). You can have your script stop when the error happens (check existence of `missfont.log` after each file, for instance), and ask a question here about the first file with which you have the issue.

Comment: What about use bash instead of Python?

Comment: How did you install TeX Live? Is `PATH` the same in both cases?

Comment: @cfr `sudo apt-get install texlive-full` `sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-all` `sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-recommended` `sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-extra` are the commands I have used.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR `mktextfm larm1200
mktextfm larm2074
mktextfm larm1440
mktextfm larm1728
mktextfm labx1728
mktextfm labx1440
mktextfm labx1200
mktextfm lati1200` These lines get printed multiple times in `missfont.log` file

Comment: Different environment, then? I asked about `PATH` already, but could be something else. Note that we have essentially no information about what's happening so our chances of getting the correct diagnosis without more details from you are minimal.

Comment: @charlesbell My point was that the errors arise not from the fact that you're batch-processing, but from individual files. Find the first file that causes the error, and ask the question about that file. (Or you can do binary search. For example, suppose you have 200 files. You can split it into files 1–100, and 101–200, and check whether you still get the error with the first half. If not, split the rest into files 101–150 and 150–200, and see if the first half of that still causes an error. Etc., until you've narrowed down a single file that causes the error.) Then, we can figure out why.